# Creating named local list in Lisp

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, programming-languages

What is the correct way of creating a local named list in Lisp? I saw global list bu I want to create a local list. Something similar to the one below

```
  (create myList)
  (push 1 myList)
```

Thanks

Comment: `let`: `(let ((test '(1 2))) (push 3 test) test) ; ==> (3 1 2)`

Comment: @Sylwester I think that comment could become a good answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use `let`. `let` creates bindings only within the given body expression. For example:

```
(let ((myList '(1 2)))
   (display myList))
; myList has gone out of scope
```